# MSI auto install

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Can I proceed auto installation of MSI file? I have an update file as MSI, so I'd like to auto install it without "Next->Next->Next" procedure and then run new application. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the msiexec command with a /qn switch.

```
msiexec /i "yourfile.msi" /qn
```

Comment: And how to run it from Admin and restart after installation?